# Keras input error for InceptionV3, expected input_1 to have shape None

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras

```python
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (None, 299, 299, 3) but got array with shape (32, 229, 229, 3)
```

Here is the core part of the code:

```python
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_batches = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('../train/',
                                 target_size=(229, 229))

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
test_batches = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('../test/',
                                 target_size=(229, 229))
#
model = keras.applications.InceptionV3(weights="imagenet")
#
clf_model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
train_history = clf_model.fit_generator(train_batches,
                    steps_per_epoch=train_batches.samples/train_batches.batch_size, 
                                        epochs=1, 
                                        validation_data = test_batches,
                    validation_steps=test_batches.samples/test_batches.batch_size )
```

Looks a weird Error. I saw other peoples error were like

```python
Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (None, 10, 3) but got array with shape (1, 3, 10)
```

or

```python
Error when checking input: expected input_1 to have shape (None, 10, 3) but got array with shape (1, 4, 16)
```

However, in my error, the shape looks fine. **Keras complains about the shape is not None...** Pls help. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input shape is not math:

```
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
train_batches = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('../train/',
                             target_size=(229, 229))

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator()
test_batches = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('../test/',
                             target_size=(229, 229))
```

change target_size=(229,229) to target_size=(299,299) for train_batches and test_batches.

Comment: Thank you so much.... It was a silly mistake of my typo... I guess I just had a long day ...